# Can't start impala after updating CDH (5.0.0 -> 5.0.2)

Tags: hadoop, impala

I wasn't able to start impala (server, state-store, catalog) after updating to cdh 5.0.2. From what I found, the startup script is expecting the executables to be found in /usr/lib/impala/sbin. There was no such directory. Instead there were /usr/lib/impala/sbin-debug and /usr/lib/impala/sbin-retail. I could finally start impala by creating a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/impala/sbin-retail /usr/lib/impala/sbin
```

However I'm still puzzled about the issue. What is the correct form to start impala. Perhaps there is some sort of config variable that lets you choose wether you want to run "debug" or "retail" version.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide. I think it can be helpful for you.
You can try to update with Cloudera Manager

Installing Impala after Upgrading Cloudera Manager
If you have just upgraded Cloudera Manager from a version that did not support Impala, the Impala software is
not installed automatically. (Upgrading Cloudera Manager does not automatically upgrade CDH or other managed
services). You can add Impala using parcels; go to the Hosts tab, and select the Parcels tab. You should see at
least one Impala parcel available for download. See Parcels for detailed instructions on using parcels to install
or upgrade Impala. If you do not see any Impala parcels available, click the Edit Settings button on the Parcels
page to go to the Parcel configuration settings and verify that the Impala parcel repo URL
(http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/parcels/latest/) has been configured in the Parcels configuration page.
See Parcel Configuration Settings for more details.

Post Installation Configuration
See The Impala Service in Managing Clusters with Cloudera Manager for instructions on configuring the Impala
service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using Cloudera Manager. I've installed (and upgraded) impala via Cloudera's yum repo.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera Manager 5.0.2 supports Impala 1.2.1 or later.

If the version of your Impala service is 1.1 or earlier the upgrade will cause the non uvailability of Impala so you need to upgrade the Impala as well to 1.2.1 or later.